# Server is unwilling to perform this operation 5003 in Active Directory

Tags: python, active-directory, ldap, openldap, python-ldap

I have tried to create a user account in LDAP. Sample code to connect the LDAP

```
    conn = ldap.initialize(bind_url)  # Connect LDAP service
    conn.set_option(ldap.OPT_REFERRALS, 0)
    conn.set_option(ldap.OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3)
    conn.set_option(ldap.OPT_DEBUG_LEVEL, 255)
    conn.set_option(ldap.OPT_X_TLS, ldap.OPT_X_TLS_DEMAND)
    conn.protocol_version = ldap.VERSION3 # Default version for LDAP protocol used
    conn.set_option(ldap.OPT_REFERRALS, 0)
    ldap_user = "CN=%s,%s" % (bind_username, base_dn)
    conn.simple_bind_s(ldap_user, bind_password) # Authentication occurs
```

I can able to connect to LDAP and create a user in disable mode (UserAccountControl == 514). When i tried to set password or enable account. There will be error like

"{'info': '0000001F: SvcErr: DSID-031A12D2, problem 5003 (WILL_NOT_PERFORM), data 0\n', 'desc': 'Server is unwilling to perform'}"

I am usin python-ldap library. Here is my sample code to add and enable user account

```
    user_attrs['objectclass'] = ['top', 'person', 'organizationalPerson', 'user']
    user_attrs['cn'] = username
    user_attrs['givenName'] = username
    user_attrs['sn'] = username
    user_attrs['displayName'] = username
    user_attrs['userAccountControl'] = '514'
    user_attrs['mail'] = str(user["email"])
    user_attrs['department'] = str(user["department"])
    user_ldif = modlist.addModlist(user_attrs)

    add_pass = [(ldap.MOD_REPLACE, 'unicodePwd', [password])]
    # 512 will set user account to enabled
    mod_acct = [(ldap.MOD_REPLACE, 'userAccountControl', '512')]
    # Add the new user account
    try:
        ldap_connection.add_s(user_dn, user_ldif)
    except ldap.LDAPError, error_message:
        print "Error adding new user: %s" % error_message
        return False

    # Add the password
    try:
        ldap_connection.modify_s(user_dn, add_pass)
    except ldap.LDAPError, error_message:
        print "Error setting password: %s" % error_message
        return False

   # Change the account back to enabled
    try:
        ldap_connection.modify_s(user_dn, mod_acct)
    except ldap.LDAPError, error_message:
        print "Error enabling user: %s" % error_message
        return False
    print "User created %s" % username
```

Anyone please let me know if there any solution or fix.

My ldap.conf in ubuntu:

TLS_CACERT      /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

Answer (score 0):

I found the following blog post to be very helpful in this regard.
http://marcitland.blogspot.com/2011/02/python-active-directory-linux.html

Looks like what you need is as follows:

```
unicode_pass = unicode('\"' + password + '\"', UNICODE_STANDARD)
password_value = unicode_pass.encode(UNICODE_ENCODING)
add_pass = [(ldap.MOD_REPLACE, 'unicodePwd', [password_value])]
```